# MariaDB - JSON_OBJECT bad encoding

Tags: mysql, json, mariadb

I've got problem with special characters when using JSON_OBJECT function in query. I am using UTF8 encoding and uft8_default_ci collation.

If i run query:

```
SELECT "Jožko Mrkvičká";
```

Output is: Jožko Mrkvičká

But if i run:

```
SELECT JSON_OBJECT("user","Jožko Mrkvičká")
```

Output is: {"user": "Jo\u017Eko Mrkvi\u010Dk�"}

This is happening only on MariaDB 10.2 server. MySQL 5.7 works fine.
Any help?
Thank you

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem. See MariaDB [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=d4c82e991c007865930bf678912ae922). See MySQL [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mQMYkmLthfH2AjWrkro6CW/0).

Comment: Then problem will be somewhere on my side. Thanks!

Comment: This is a known and not yet fixed bug https://jira.mariadb.org/browse/MDEV-13633 . You can track it further in JIRA.

Comment: That Jira mentions PHP's json_encode. Is that being used by the client code? Or MariaDB? In any case, use this as a second argument: `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` whenever calling `json_encode`. (This requires PHP 5.4.0.)

Comment: Can't reproduce the error: http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=9d0be29f1eebbe54ad1f5b66e78a0c77 Where do read the output ?